# Semicircular function is convex and lower semicontinuous function

Tags: convex-analysis

I want to know how to show that
$$f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{\bar{R}},\; f(x)=\begin{cases}
-\sqrt{1-x^2} & if\; |x| \leq 1 \\
+\infty & \, \text{ortherwise}
\end{cases}$$
is convex and lower semicontinuous.

I know that in case $|x|\leq 1$, it can draw as the semicircular function which is obvious convex by the picture. But I still can not show through the definition. Do you have any suggestion for this?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** If $|x|, |y| \le 1$, you have
$$
\left\|\begin{pmatrix}x\\ f(x)\end{pmatrix}\right\| = 1
,\qquad
\left\|\begin{pmatrix}y\\ f(y)\end{pmatrix}\right\| = 1.
$$
For $z = \lambda x + (1-\lambda) y$ with $\lambda \in [0,1]$, you have
$$
\left\|\begin{pmatrix}z\\ \lambda f(x) + (1-\lambda) f(y)\end{pmatrix}\right\| \le 1
$$
by the triangle inequality.

Comment: Excuse me, I don't understand what is $\vert \left( \begin{array}{c} x\\ f(x) \end{array}\right)\vert$ mean.

Comment: This is the Euclidean norm of a vector with two elements.